# VMWare ESXi 5.0 Networking Issue

Tags: vmware-esxi, connection, vmware-server, arp, juniper

I have an issue with 2 new ESXi hosts.
OS - ESXi5.0 Custom Dell ISO patched up to Build 1024429

DELL R820 with 1G network 2 ports from integrated MB NIC(Intel) connected to 2 juniper switches, one is active, one is standby lose connectivity intermittently.

When they lose connectivity i can ping neighbor hosts on the same subnet connected to the same switch but pinging default getaway returns:

```
"sendto() failed (Host is down)"
```

From esxcli I see nothing in ARP table for default getaway ip issuing a command when connectivity is lost:

```
esxcli network ip neighbor list
```

Tcpdump from esxicli shows that esxi host constantly sends ARP broadcast for the default getaway IP but never gets the response. 
I have actually 6 new servers and only 2 of them are having these problems.
Same hardware and same settings for ESXi, This connections are for 1G Management network.

Does any have slight idea what can be wrong?

Comment: have you looked at the switch logs?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have access to switch, i did opened the ticket with network group. but i did follow VMWare suggestions for juniper switches and passed them to network team: 1) use LACP active on both ends 2) Disable juniper hashing on the switch side.

Comment: You can't use LACP unless you have vSphere Enterprise Plus - are you really sure you have this?

Comment: Yes, We do have vSphere Enterprise Plus.

Comment: And you're using distributed switches (VDS)?

Comment: Yes. we use distributed switches.

Comment: Then I guess that your network team hasn't done their job, if the setup is identical across the other hosts. I really can't find any other reason for two hosts losing one link from time to time.

Comment: yeah, it is very weird. but what would disallow on the switch not to send response of ARP request to that port?

Comment: Unless there is a LACP configuration on the switch side I guess it would see mac adress(es) flap from one port to another. I don't know much about Juniper, but it could be shutting down the port as a risk measure.

Comment: Thank you. At this point will wait on network team to respond.

Comment: Make sure that iphash is disabled. Sometimes if link aggregation is set on one end and not the other you can get problems

Comment: yeah iphash is disabled on juniper side

Comment: Please post your configuration from the Juniper switch.